# Linux-Ubuntu / i want to see files in the directory and number of files

Tags: linux, files

I want to see files in the directory (desktop) and number of files in shell script.
How can I do it?

I found this, is it right?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Files:"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f

echo "Number of files:"
ls -Anq | grep -c '^-'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for `find` here.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# nullglob: make patterns that don't match expand to nothing
# dotglob: also expand patterns to hidden names
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

names=( * )    # all names in the current directory
regular_files=()

# separate out regular files into the "regular_files" array
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    # the -L test is true for symbolic links, we want to skip these
    if [[ -f $name ]] && [[ ! -L $name ]]; then
        regular_files+=( "$name" )
    fi
done

printf 'There are %d names (%d regular files)\n' "${#names[@]}" "${#regular_files[@]}"
printf 'The regular files are:\n'
printf '\t%s\n' "${regular_files[@]}"
```

Or, with `zsh`,

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

# "ND" corresponds to setting nullglob and dotglob for the pattern
names=( *(ND) )
regular_files=( *(.ND) )   # "." selects only regular files

printf 'There are %d names (%d regular files)\n' "${#names[@]}" "${#regular_files[@]}"
printf 'The regular files are:\n'
printf '\t%s\n' "${regular_files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The find is correct, but [you should not parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), not even to find the number of files. Since you have GNU find, opt for

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Files:"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f

echo "Number of files:"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf . | wc -c
```

The second `find` prints a `.` for each file and then `wc` counts the number of dots.

Comment: Thank you for help